# PostgreSQL MAX aggregate function applied to strings and Java resultset

Tags: java, string, postgresql, max, aggregate-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table "t" with a column "c" which type is "character varying(32)".

Values in this column look like this: "2014100605".

I am using the "MAX()" aggregate function to retrieve the maximum value in this column.

```
SELECT MAX(c) AS max FROM t;
```

In Java, if I prepare the query above, get a "resultSet" object and send it the getString("max") message, I get max = null.

If I send it the getInt("max") method instead, I get the result I'm expecting, something like "2014100605".

Is this normal behavior?

Am I really allowed to do this or am I getting the expected result randomly?

Is "MAX()" actually using the lexicographical order?

A bit of Java code:

```
s_preparedSqlQuery = 
  "SELECT MAX(quotinv_nro) AS quotinv_nro_max "
+ "FROM imw_quotation_invoice "
+ "WHERE quotinv_type = ? "
+ "AND quotinv_nro LIKE '" + s_quotinvDate + "%'";

preparedStatement = m_connection.prepareStatement(s_preparedSqlQuery);
preparedStatement.setString(1, s_quotinvType);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if(resultSet != null)
{
    if(resultSet.next())
    {
        // s_quotinvNroMax = resultSet.getString("quotinv_nro_max");
        n_quotinvNroMax = resultSet.getInt("quotinv_nro_max");
            
        // if(s_quotinvNroMax == null)
        if(n_quotinvNroMax == 0)
        {
            n_nbQuotinvsThisSameDate = 0;
            return n_nbQuotinvsThisSameDate;
        }
        else
        {
            s_quotinvNroMax = Integer.toString(n_quotinvNroMax);
            n_length = s_quotinvDate.length();
            s_currentMaxNro = s_quotinvNroMax.substring(n_length - 1);
            n_nbQuotinvsThisSameDate = Integer.valueOf(s_currentMaxNro);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your complete Java code. But in general: max on a varchar column will use ascii sorting, so the value `2` will bigger than `10`. The root cause of your problem is that you chose the wrong data type in the database. Your value looks suspiciously like a date or timestamp. If that is the case, use a `date` or `timestamp` column and all comparisons will magically work as you expect them. If that is a plain number, use `integer`.

Comment: I suspect there is a name clash using `max` as column name - try something else, like `maxx`.

Comment: I've tried to edit my first post: I couldn't format the code properly. I've been trying for tens of minutes, it's driving me nuts. Can't we do without it?

Comment: According to this documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html the "MAX()" aggregate function can be used for the following argument types: "any array, numeric, string, or date/time type". 
In my case, the type of the argument of the "MAX()" function is "character varying(32)".

Comment: I'm actually using "quotinv_nro_max"  as an alias for "MAX(quotinv_nro)" in the SQL query.

Comment: I just added a little bit of Java code as an edit to my first post.

Comment: I never said you can not use `max()` on a varchar. It just behaves according to the comparison rules for *characters* even if your `varchar` column indeed contains a number. If you have two strings in your column `'2'` and `'10'` then max will return `'2'`. If you have two numbers in an integer column: `2` and `10` then max will return `10`. Using `getInt()` on a column that is a varchar is another problem. You shouldn't do that.  I'm not sure what will happen if the string data isn't a valid number. All this seems to really indicate that you have chosen the wrong data type for your column.

Comment: Ok. You are right. I didn't read carefully enough. I just checked: the "maximum" between '2' and '10' is '2' like you said.
As for the type I chose, I'll stick with it because it's not a date nor an integer even if it looks like a little bit of the two.
But I won't go on using this "MAX()" function for character varying typed data because it doesn't suit my needs. I'll use another method. So thank you for your explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting on a unique Id column....

```
int maxID = 0;
Statement s2 = con.createStatement();
s2.execute("SELECT MAX(UniqueId) FROM MyTable");    
ResultSet rs2 = s2.getResultSet(); 

if (rs2.next()) 
{
  maxID = rs2.getInt(1);
}
```

If you are hitting on any other non-key column....

```
int maxID = 0;
Statement s2 = con.createStatement();
s2.execute("SELECT MAX(ColumnValue) FROM MyTable");    
ResultSet rs2 = s2.getResultSet(); 

while (rs2.next()) 
{
  maxID = rs2.getInt(1);
}
```